# Deploy multiple war in Jetty

Tags: maven, plugins, deployment, jetty

I am using jetty maven plugin to deploy some wars. 
I have 2 modules:
moduleA.war at port 8180
moduleB.war at port 8380

When I deploy the war using the maven jetty plugin, both webapps are trying to run at port 8180 even though I am setting up connectors for both application. Here is my pom configuration for doing this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3.v20100526</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8180</port>
                        <name>instance_8180</name>                      
                    </connector>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8380</port>
                        <name>instance_8380</name>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>                   
                <contextHandlers>
                    <!-- <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext"> -->
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                        <war>/${project.build.directory}/user-mgmt-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</war> 
                        <contextPath>/user-mgmt-web</contextPath>
                        <connectorNames>
                            <item>instance_8180</item>
                        </connectorNames>
                    </contextHandler>
                    <!-- <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext"> -->
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                        <war>/${project.build.directory}/services-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</war> 
                        <contextPath>/services-web</contextPath>
                        <connectorNames>
                            <item>instance_8380</item>
                        </connectorNames>
                    </contextHandler>
                </contextHandlers>
                <stopPort>80</stopPort>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I would like to know how to make the second webapp deployed start at its assigned port. 
When I run it, when the container finishes initializing the second webapp, i get an address already in use error.

Assane

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am new to using stack overflow. I will go back and accept answers from my previous questions.

Comment: if you look at my pom, i am using context handlers and for each context i am assigning a connector with a port number. Does it make sense or I am missing something?

Comment: It makes sense. I don't run my projects that way, I use a single instance and was just offering that as a suggestion. It sounds like you're intending to run it on multiple ports and that you're intending to do that. If this question is still open later I may dig into it more to see if I can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two different module with two different port works only in multiple instance,In your case only first port no is activated set idle timeout for first port.

```
<port>8180</port>
<maxIdleTime>"put your time"</maxIdleTime>
```

Then start another port.

If above not work try this one below

In your jetty.xml add new connector

```
<!-- original connector on port 8080 -->
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>

<!-- new connector on port 8081 --> 
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I ended up overlaying the wars and running the webapps on the same port. It was the quickest path to get something done. I just adjusted my soapui project that I was ultimately testing to run on the same port. I still will spend some time trying to solve how to run the wars in the same container using different ports when time allows me to, seems like i might have to edit the jetty.xml file possibly